# html <object> tag has unexpected behavior with local file in React Native / Expo

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm working on a dual web/mobile application using Expo.  In my web view for desktop, I'm loading a pdf inside a `Modal` component like this:

```
import { Modal } from "react-native"

<Modal visible={props.visible} onRequestClose={props.onClose}>
  <Pressable style={styles.centeredView } onPress={e => onClickOutside(e, props.onClose)}>
    <View style={styles.modalBody}>
      <object data="../assets/pdfs/currentPromo.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="700px">
        <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="./assets/pdfs/currentPromo.pdf">to the PDF!</a></p>
      </object>
    </View>
  </Pressable>
</Modal>
```

This code creates a flashing effect where it appears that my entire web page is being loaded inside the modal. It starts flashing and repeatedly reloading the page.

However, when I change the object's "data" attribute to a public html link such as "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", the code works as expected.

I'm certain that this isn't a file routing issue, because I reference the same folder without issue elsewhere in this file. Removing the `<p>` tag also changes nothing.

Does an `<object>` tag not work well with React Native? Why does it work with a link? Am I missing something more obvious?

Thanks.